# How long does VPython take to update position of objects

Tags: python, vpython

I'm creating a virtual pool/billiards game using VPython.  I'd like to have it update the position every dt amount of "time"  (I'm using rate() to limit the loop time), not faster.

My calculations for position look ahead to any potential collisions 0

eg:  If dt=1, and I detect a collision at .25s, I advance positions by .25s, calculate new velocities, then check for collisions in the next 0.75 seconds.  This repeats until collisions are not detected in the current time jump.  I would then like to show this change of position of the objects.  (then rate() causes a wait until the next time through)

**My question is this:**  Is it faster to do the vector math by pulling stuff like sphere.position = sphere.position+sphere.velocity*t1
---or---
before detecting collisions changing all positions and velocities vectors into tuples and back to vectors, then doing the vector math, then converting to tuples then vectors before assigning the new t=t+dt position/velocity values.

The conversion is necessary because vectors are mutable data, and therefore pulling the values to new variables and doing the math still changes the sphere.position values and therefore causes position to update on the screen.

Essentially, does Vpython put other processes on hold while it updates the position visually, or does that run as fast as it can while the numbers crunch as fast as they can?

Let me know if I need to explain something more clearly

EDIT:

Realized I can use a cheap solution for this.

```
>>> h=vector(5,6,2)
>>> j=h
>>> j.mag*=2
>>> j
vector(10, 12, 4)
>>> h
vector(10, 12, 4)
```

The above segment shows what happens if you directly copy a vector.  But if you multiply by one during the copy, it makes a new vector since technically the value was changed, but numerically it's the same

```
>>> k=h*1
>>> k
vector(10, 12, 4)
>>> k*=2
>>> k
vector(20, 24, 8)
>>> h
vector(10, 12, 4)
```

Comment: The answer to question such as "Is it faster to do ... or ..." is very easy: "try both and compare performance". Unfortunately many time, there isn't any better answer. Up to my knowledge, this is one of those time.

Comment: So I might as well just do it in the way that is less complicated to code.  Ideally they would have a refresh position command that would update everything's location when you call it